# nginx set up reverse proxy from subfolder to a port

Tags: http, nginx, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to set up a Nginx reverse proxy and I'm slowly losing my mind trying to figure it out.

I have my Nginx server listening at 80, and it performs great. I have a page with a form where I want to be able to send `.json` POSTs from that page to a Python HTTP server that can process the requests. I have the server at port 8000.

On the website, I want to be able to reach the server by navigating to `<IP>:/sub/folder/` so that I can send the `.json` POSTs from my `<IP>:/sub/index.html` page by making a simple relative request to `./folder`.

When I send a curl to `<IP>:8000`, I reach the server and get the correct response.

I have tried to set up Nginx `proxy_pass` with the following configuration:

```
location /sub/folder/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
}
```

This results in a 301 which sends me from `<url>/sub/folder` to `/sub/folder/`, followed by a 404 at `/sub/folder/`.

If I go back to the Nginx config and turn `/sub/folder/` into `/sub/folder`, navigating to `<url>/sub/folder` returns a 404.

I've tried using `https`, I've tried changing out `127.0.0.1` for `localhost`, I've tried removing the final `/` in the `proxy_pass` line, I've tried proxying to `https://<IP>:<port>/sub/folder` even though the HTTP server is at root, among more.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.